# Javascript RegEx to match all whitespaces except between special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need a regEx to match all whitespaces except those inside @ signs to make a correct split.

I have this string:

```
[0] == @Item 1@
```

With the split I need the following array (with or without @ in 3rd element):

```
var array = ["[0]","==","@Item 1@"];
```

With a simple split(" ") I get this:

```
var array = ["[0]","==","@Item","1@"];
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = '[0] == @Item 1@';
console.log( text.match(/(?:@[^@]*@|\S)+/g) )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDR0JY/1). The `(?:@[^@]*@|\S)+` pattern means:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `@[^@]*@` - a `@` char, zero or more chars other than `@` and then a `@` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\S` - any non-whitespace char
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times.

The `/g` flat tells `.match()` to extract all occurrences.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: Hello, I have another cuestion, it's critical and I've tried a solution based on this but it did not work. How can I get all the parentheses except those between @ and @? I need to remove all outside parentheses.  Example:
`
( [15] == @val1@ || [15] == @val 2 (dont select these)@ )  &&  ( [5] == @val 3@ || [5] == @val 4@ )`

Comment: @LauraEld "*I need to remove all outside parentheses.*" - doesn't it mean you need to extract them? `Array.from(text_str.matchAll(/@[^@]*@|(\([^()]*\))/g), x => x[1]).filter(Boolean)`?